# how to use triple nested quotes in django tempates?

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

i'm trying to use inline CSS and loading an image as a background in Django template.
i need three quotes but don't know how to do it.
how can i fix the code bellow?

`<div class="full-background" style="background-image: url("{% static '/img/curved-images/white-curved.jpg' %}")"></div>`

Comment: Where are you using the three quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing because you are using double quotes inside double quotes

Here is how it would look without the Django static files declaration

```
<div class="full-background" style="background-image: url('path/to/file')"></div>
```

Note the single quotes around the url path

If you want to use Django static files, just use single quotes outside and inside the static declaration

```
    <div 
       class="full-background" 
       style="background-image: url('{% static '/img/curved-images/white-curved.jpg' %}')"
    ></div>
```

Django will not see the outside single quotes when it looks for the static files.