# Django expected css(css-rparantexpected) when trying to add image to <body id ="bg" >

Tags: html, css, django, background

https://paste.pics/H6N16
So here is how my project is organised, I followed a youtube tutorial and for me it shows that paretentheses are missing, maybe that can be due to the bad folder management, I'm not sure

> **<body id = "bg" style="background-image: url('{% static "image/patient_doctor.png" %}');">**

Dont know what to do :/

Comment: The IDE might complain about that due to the nested quotes but do you _actually_ get an error when you run that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use triple nested quotes in django tempates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71835317/how-to-use-triple-nested-quotes-in-django-tempates)

Comment: Try this one `<body id = "bg" style="background-image: url({% static 'image/patient_doctor.png' %});">`

Comment: I did that but again the same problem showed up. weirdly it works when i put after "bg" no white space, im not sure why: <body id = "bg"style= "background-image: url('{% static 'image/doc.png' %}');">

Answer (score 0):

install django ( beauty sysntax ) extensions fix this problem, then select language mode : django HTML

Answer (score 0):

try this `<body id = "bg" style="background-image: url('static/image/patient_doctor.png')">`

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.